# How do I add the Clickable library to the p5.js web editor?

Tags: p5.js

I want to add the Clickable library to my sketch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="stages.js"></script>
    <script src="ball.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What do I put in the HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about [this](https://github.com/Lartu/p5.clickable) library?

If so, you need either the `p5.clickable.js` or the `p5.clickable.min.js` file. You need to host it the same way you're currently hosting your `sketch.js`, `stages.js`, and `ball.js` files.

If you're using the P5.js editor, then you can upload these files using the `Sketch > Add File` menu.